# Sort data into blocks

Tags: bash, sorting

I am a beginner in programming, so the question is probably trivial.

I would like to get from:

```
1   sth
2   sth
3   sth
4   sth
3   sth
2   sth
2   sth
```

To:

```
1 sth

2 sth
2 sth 
2 sth

3 sth
3 sth

4 sth
```

This is format required by gnuplot for a heatmap. I know you can sort the data by the first number in the line using: `sort -n "datafile"`, but how do you split everything into blocks? Thanks.

Comment: The blocks are needed only if you supply full coordinates. See http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply choroba. This is exactly what I have in datafile - three columns: x, y and f(x, y). My question is just simplified :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of makes it:

```
$ sort -n file | awk '{if (a!=$1) {print ""} a=$1}1'

1   sth

2   sth
2   sth
2   sth

3   sth
3   sth

4   sth
```

#### Explanation

- `sort -n file` is clear, as you already used it.
- `awk '{if (a!=$1) {print ""} a=$1}1'`

  - whenever the first field of one line and the next one is different, print a new line.
  - this is accomplished by saving the first field value (`$1`) in the variable `a`.
  - the `{}1` condition prints each one of the lines.

Comment: You are welcome. I was once recommened to read http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ and helped me a lot.

Comment: Your explanation and reference cited crarified a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Perl solution:

```
sort -n datafile | perl -ape 'print "\n" if defined $previous and $F[0] != $previous; $previous = $F[0]'
```